# How to use of external class without specifying them in #include directives?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I have a solution compose of many C++ projects and most of them use the "std::string" class. However, there's not a single #include directive for the  header which results in many C2039: 'string' is not a member of 'std' fatal errors. Therefore, whoever previously made the solution must have a way to tell Visual Studio to auto-include the  header. How can I do such things?

Comment: While it is possible with `/FI` you should modify each header referencing `std::string` class to directly include appropriate header instead.

Comment: Ah yes, the pain of inheriting a project with improper includes that "just happened" to work for the original author!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Every time someone tell me that it work on their computer I ask them why they didn't just sent their computer to prod X)

Comment: @3Nd_R1m Heh, don't tempt them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on VTT's comment, I found that you can "Force include" file in `Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Advanced` and add "(header name)" to the `Forced include File` field. That's one way to do it.